# Are Ord and Enum sometimes incompatible in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Could `Ord` and `Enum` be one typeclass? Why doesn't `Enum` require `Eq`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Enum` represents types that can be mapped to/from integers. This doesn't say anything about how those types should be sorted, merely that you can represent them with integers.

`Ord` represents ordered types. This is different than types that can be mapped to integers. For example, you can't map arbitrary-precision floating point values to integers, but you *can* order them. And while you technically could try and map Floats to integers, nobody in their right mind would do so.

As for `Eq`, `Ord` requires this because it doesn't make sense to have a totally ordered datatype that doesn't support equality. However, `Enum` has no need for `Eq`. Since `Enum` doesn't provide any ordering guarantees, it doesn't provide equality guarantees either.

Comment: It's not quite true that it wouldn't make sense to have `Ord` without `Eq`, take floating point numbers for example.

Comment: Enum represents types that can be mapped to/from integers. Integers can be tested for equality. Is there an instance of `Enum` which doesn't want `Eq`?

Comment: @TiloWiklund well if you're saying that floating point numbers shouldn't have an `Eq` instance, then they shouldn't have an `Ord` instance, either. They should instead only have `Min` and `Max` [Semigroup](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/semigroups/latest/doc/html/Data-Semigroup.html#Semigroup) instances.

Comment: @L01man: I don't know, but if `Enum` depended on `Ord` that would imply it relies upon the specific implementation of `Ord`, and yet your datatype may want to sort differently than the `Enum`-mapped integers do.

Comment: @KevinBallard: You can still define your own instance of `Ord`. What about `Eq` and `Enum`?

Comment: @L01man: What about it? Why would `Enum` necessarily require `Eq`?

Comment: @KevinBallard Good point, had a brain fart and didn't think of antireflexivity :)

Comment: @KevinBallard: If things can be enumerated, they have their own place in the enumeration, thus they can be compared for equality with their place as the criteria... Maybe.

Comment: @L01man: If you want that, just use `sortBy (comparing fromEnum)`.

Answer (score 12):

There are things that can be enumerated without an order. For example:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue deriving Enum
```

Which order should colors have? There is no inherent order, even though the colors can be enuemrated.

There are also things that can be enumerated but not compared for equality. Floats, for example, have a NaN value that isn't equal to anything. Floats can be enumerated, however.

Comment: Why isn't the ordering simply the sequential order? So `compare Red Green` is `LT`, `compare Green Blue` is `LT`.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong, it could be, but in a given use case it doesn't necessarily make sense for it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not sure to what extent this is generally accepted, but I've always viewed `Enum` as a typeclass describing types with canonical *total preorders* (i.e. there might be a loop) such that the sequence of terms "between" any pair of terms is finite (witnessed by `enumFromTo`).

`Ord`, on the other hand, describes types with canonical *total orders*, without any requirement that the set of elements between any pair of terms be finite.